# Switch firmware to enable U.S. cellular phone towers on LG V50 ThinQ?

Tags: lg, device-firmware, mobile-network, baseband

I had bought an LG V50 ThinQ a few months back to exchange with my old phone. However, lately, people have been calling me and it goes straight to voicemail from time to time.

It turns out that I have the Korean version (V500N), and it's not as compatible with U.S. cellular phone towers or whatever.

Would it be possible to change the phone's Korean firmware to USA's?

Comment: I assume by "compatible with U.S cellular phone towers" you are referring to the bands/frequencies supported by the device in 4G/5G. Only those bands can be used that are supported by both, cell tower and phone. Unfortunately I would be surprised if the supported bands could be changes by replacing the firmware. To my knowledge the frequencies an antenna is sensitive to is determined by it's length, thus it is a physical restriction and nothing you can change by a firmware.